# How to fix "Bad escape sequence in string" in schema description

Tags: javascript, schema, google-tag-manager, json-ld

I have use GTM to tag the schema variables.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name": "{{Product-name}}",
  "description": "{{Product-description}}",
  "category": "{{Product-category}}",
  "image": "{{Product-image}}",
  "sku": "{{Product-reference}}",
  "offers": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "url": "{{Page Path}}",
    "Price": "{{Product-price-with-dot}}",
    "priceCurrency": "[EUR]",
    "itemCondition": "https://schema.org/NewCondition",
    "availability": "{{Product-stock}}",
    "seller": {
      "@type": "Corporation",
      "name": "Company Name"
    }
 }
}
</script>
```

All seems OK except for the variable value "Description" of some products whose description contains special characters.
The original text is converted with more and more special caracteres... and return "Bad escape sequence in string".

[Product-description variable set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0mBm.jpg)

Original text description :

```
id="pPdtDesc">Shopping bag.
```

[Product description with "Bad escape sequence in string" result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1ENq.png)

How can I fix all any possible problems with special characters?

Comment: remove the backslashes.

Comment: backslashes are created by the called variable not by me...

Comment: show what's in those variables then.

Comment: As in my image named “Product description with Bad escape sequence in string result” but without the special characters.

Comment: No, show how it's set up in GTM.

Comment: Just updated the « Product-description variable set up » image. You can see now my script, my variable and the result :-) Should I add a custom JavaScript function? If yes what is the full script?

Comment: Ah, ok, no. You don't want a variable returning an element. You want to select the element you want via CJS and take its innerHTML or value, or whatever other property you actually want.

Comment: Yes  I want select  the value (here the real text description as show on my website) without any special characters :-)

Comment: No, that's what I'm saying. Your variable selects an element. Rewrite it to CJS that selects the element from dom and returns its value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers was :

```html
function(){
var string = {{Product-description}};
return string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        "@type": "Question",
            "name": "What is Cooper Kupp\'s major?",
            "acceptedAnswer": {
                "@type": "Answer",
                "text": "Cooper graduated from Eastern Washington University, majoring in Economics."
```

Comment: What is wrong in this code it keep showing Structured data with syntax errors detected Bad escape sequence in string please help me out

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).